# how to restrict to only single file upload in upload documents control in kendo ui

Tags: kendo-ui

how to restrict to only single file upload in upload documents control in kendo UI.
is there any property to check the number of files uploaded.

Comment: Check if [`multiple`](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/upload/configuration/multiple) option set to `false` works for you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would handle the selected event of the uploader: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/upload/events/select

In the event, you would get the length of the existing files collection using the getFiles method of the uploader: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/upload/methods/getfiles

If the length of the existing files collection plus the length of the incoming file collection exceeds 1, then display an error:

```js
$("#my-uploader").kendoUpload({
  select: function(e) {
    var existingFileLength = e.sender.getFiles().length;
    var incomingFileLength = e.files.length;
    if (existingFileLength + incomingFileLength > 1) {
      kendo.alert('You can only upload one file.');
      e.preventDefault();
    }
  }
});
```

Dojo: https://dojo.telerik.com/aDOfICID

**Update**

Or as DontVoteMeDown suggested, the simpler method would be to set the multiple property to false: https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/upload/configuration/multiple

Comment: Isn't better to use [`multiple: false`](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/upload/configuration/multiple) in that case ?

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown - You're correct; I didn't realize that I was trying to over-engineer it.